# Driving 7segment with PWM using output-enable pin on shift register

Tags: transistors, pwm, shift-register

*EDIT: After short discussion and walking through ESP documentation, I decided to throw up PWM using OE pin (ESP does not have HW PWM), and use do it as part of multiplexing as Kartman suggested. Thanks*

I'm doing very original project you never heard of - a clock. It will be my first use of PNP/NPN (especially the high-driver side) and shift registers, one reason to not use any led driver.

The project will be supplied by 9V, controlled by ESP8266 which will feed two 74HC595 by data. All transistors should be their SMD versions (bought as MMBT3904 and MMBT3906). The 7 segments display are some cheap chinese, common cathode, most probably with two red LEDs (their voltage drop is little bit below 4V).

The whole schematic would be pretty huge, so I'm pasting just the part I'm concerned about - driving one segment on one display. There will be two SR (shift registers), one (SR1) for driving actual segments and one (SR2) for driving low-side (common cathode) - basically for "selecting" a display to display number on.

And, I would like to add a special function - dimming, which I would like to achieve using PWM-ing an OE pin, which should change "Input from SR1" to open collector. In my head and on the paper, it works. However before I order the PCB and start endless soldering of few hundreds of pins, I would like to ask you, more experienced:

- Is it even a good idea?
- Will this design work at all?
- Does it have some major (or minor) flaws?

Thank you (and sorry for little bit lame question)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSnVkZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please draw Q3 the right way up! I.e. emitter pointing down. It does make understanding the circuit much easier. R2,6 and 7 seem way too low in value. I’d suggest you recalculate the values.  You could use something like a tpic6b595 to simplify things a bit. You could dim using the OE or do it as part of your multiplexing code.

Comment: Why don't you just run the simulation? You have the circuit already drawn in the simulator; you could answer your own questions in a few seconds.

Comment: @Kartman is it better this way? I'm sorry, I never did schematics for others, just for myself. You are right about R2, 6, 7 - you are right. If I understand it correctly, to safely saturate I need just around 2mA, so I will use 560R. Is it OK? 

Dimming as part of multiplexing seems much better idea, thanks!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: hi, I did simulation (in ltspice) and it looked to me OK. But it won't show for example that something will burn, create some RF interference or whatever.

Comment: There's not really enough here to go on. If you have  (say) 18mA per segment and 4 digits plus colon that's as much as ~500mA (a bit less because 88:88  is not a valid time), but in any case way too much for a 2N3906.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany wait, where did you get 500mA? Let's count 20mA for every segment, that's 140mA for 2N3904 as low-side digit driver - for maximally 1/4 of the time. And only 20mA for 2N3906 as a high-side segment driver. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know what your circuit is, so I assumed the worst-case, static drive and one driver for all the commons.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what you see is driving one segment. Hi-side drivers are connected to one specific segment of all digits whereas low-sides are connected to common cathodes of single digits. If everything works as it should, only one digit at a certain time should be driven. But even if there is some software error and I do "ALL ON", still the low-sides would be driving just one digit (120mA) and hi-sides would be driving one specific segment on all displays (80mA). Only total consumption will be over.

Comment: @MikeS. - Hi, Do I understand correctly that your edit to the question a few minutes ago, is the conclusion to the topic? If so, since answers should be written in the box below and not edited into the question, can you please consider writing a "[self-answer](/help/self-answer)" with as much detail as you can, in the box labeled "Your Answer" below? You can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) your own answer once 48 hours has elapsed since you asked the question (meaning a self-answer can be accepted after 01:05 UTC on April 11). Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson: well, as the circuit is probably correct (having only to change few values), than yes. But I think deletion of this question would be better, as it probably have no value for others...

Comment: @MikeS. - Hi, Many thanks for clarifying. If you *really* want to delete your question (as long as no-one else adds an answer) there is a "Delete" link which you can use, below the question (near the "Share, Cite, Edit ..." links) when the page is viewed on a desktop browser (or on a mobile browser in "desktop mode"). However I think the question does have some value :-) It's up to you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have decided to do it little bit different way.

ESP8266 does not have hardware PWM, so it would have to be done in SW. As it seems to be an sub-ideal solution, I decided to use just multiplexing code to do dimming as suggested in comments. 74HC595 are fast enough to do it.